# Draw "star rating" chart with R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm looking for a way to draw "star rating" style graphs in R, similar to a bar chart, but with star symbols. I guess integers would be the input, or possibly half-marks, like "three and a half stars".

Not even sure what these charts are called to search existing packages...

Happy to tackle a manual solution, but looking for some good starting points.

Comment: `ggplot::geom_dotplot` is close (with `method = "histodot"`), but I'm not sure how to change the shape from a dot to a star. I was hoping `shape = "\u2605"` would work, but it doesn't. Surprisingly, even `shape = "*"` and `shape = 8` don't seem to work. And it wouldn't work well for non-integer star values...

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1111) is quite old but seems to explain why `geom_dotplot` does not support the parameter `shape`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say the answer is "nah". Maybe too lowbrow application for R? :D

Thanks for the comments and direction - will look at roll-my-own sol'n.

Comment: Haven't had any luck finding an existing package. Easiest to make an empty plot, and add single character text at the location of each "star". Just need to wrestle with a font that allows unicode dingbats.